# What are some good resource for programmers to design icons?

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations

I'm a programmer and find myself needing to draw icons frequently. Does anyone have any good resources for both the tools and how to design icons?

Comment: Paint (j/k)! for favicons you can play with [favicon.cc](http://www.favicon.cc/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best icon set I've used has to be the [Fugue Icon](http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/) set by Yusuke Kamiyamane. The set is licensed under the Creative Common Attribution License and royalty-free for a reasonable fee. It's a great deal considering there are 3300+ detailed icons. You also get the PSD files too. I find these icons are especially good for web apps. The down side is they're 16x16.

If you want to create your own, I suggest reading tutorials on http://tutsplus.com, especially http://vector.tutsplus.com since icons should be created in vector for scaling..

Comment: _vector for scaling_ is true for any other images. But if you want a good icon set, you should do it in vector (lazy way :D) and then refactor it almost pixel per pixel for every size and moreover for small resolution icons and their readability.

Answer (score 3):

[IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/) is nice. You can open a PNG file here and save it as an icon file. I use this.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio (especially 2010) includes a large set of icons, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip`

Comment: Yes, well - this is a good resource for picking from a set of  standard windows toolbar buttons, but not really a good resource for designing icons. I use it a lot when I don't have time to create any of my own.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OS X, I tend to like [Pixen](http://pixen.en.softonic.com/mac), myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Greenfish Icon Editor Pro](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Editors/Greenfish-Icon-Editor-Pro.shtml). It is totally free of charge! It is by far the best free icon editor I have ever tried. I specially like the feature to replace a color component with transparency. This is great to remove a background color and preserving smooth edges on the image.

From the description of the product on the download site:

> GFIE Pro is a powerful icon, cursor, animation and icon library editor. **Layer support** with advanced selection handling makes it a really professional and unique freeware tool for designing small pixelgraphic images. GFIE offers high-quality **filters** like Bevel, Drop Shadow and Glow; supports editing **animated cursors** and managing **icon libraries**. It's lightweight (< 1.8 MB unzipped) and also has a portable version - just unpack it to your USB drive and use it anywhere. A clean, customizable, **multilanguage user interface** makes it really **easy to learn and use**.

Answer (score 0):

I am a great fan of Icomoon. Loads and loads of free icons. You can upload your own svg-images (made in, for example illustrator) and then have a complete set scalable, easily accessible icons: http://icomoon.io/

Answer (score 0):

A good place to find inspiration for icons as well as downloadable icons themselves is:

- [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/), which aims to have a vector icons for every noun. Icons here are high contrast black and white ones.