# icon / design element database / site?

Tags: icon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are some good places to find free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-free-stock-images)

Are there good central locations for icons / buttons / ui elements?

There are a number of great font databases online, good stock image sellers, and even a good number of blogs that point to good designs / themes / templates... but icons / ui elements?

Also, is there a standard of any kind that specifies what images / shapes should be in a complete set?

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-are-some-good-resource-for-programmers-to-design-icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's tons of them. Google will lead you to many.

Iconfactory is perhaps the most well known. But icon sets are a dime a dozen these days.

There's also some very nice open source sets. Blueprint.css, for instance, leverages the very nice Silk Sprites:

http://www.famfamfam.com/

There are no standards for icons, but are common symbols that can be leveraged.

Comment: yeah, I had seen icon factory... that site is impossible to navigate. On myfonts.com all I have to do is click on "latest" and I get like 100 fonts... boom. Its hard not to get an eyeful. Is there something I am missing on icon factory?

Comment: http://www.iconspedia.com - decent number of sets. Each category gives you 21 samples per page from that set. Spammy. Difficult to navigate.

Comment: http://www.iconshock.com - lots of 3d icons. You can see samples of all the sets on one page (thanks!). The icons are not really design elements for a webpage though... more like Wii game elements.

Comment: http://www.designfloat.com/ - not specific to icons... sort of digg for design. Great place to search

Comment: http://deviantart.com - the best - honestly, the easiest to use / browse / search. Even though it is not specific to the genre (icons) it has by far the greatest number of icon sets.

Comment: http://www.iconfinder.com - this is the place I was probably looking for in my question, but coupled with deviantart... you'll find what you need. Great usability.

Comment: Do note the licenses on Devniant art, though. Many are non-commercial.

Answer (score 0):

Smashing Magazine has a bunch: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/freebies/

Comment: yeah... smashing magazine has a lot of good articles too. I am not looking for freebies, I am looking for the mother collection... like the site(s) where are the illustrators go to list their work.

Comment: @Sy if you're looking for the site where the illustrators go to list their work, then you're looking for http://dribbble.com/

Answer (score 0):

For ui elements you should check http://365psd.com